# Extract number of Google search results using `rvest`

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I would like to extract the number of Google search results using `rvest` R package:

I used the following without success

```
require(dplyr)
require(rvest)
"https://www.google.com/search?q=Diversity" %>% 
  rvest::session() %>% 
  rvest::html_elements(xpath = '//*[@id="result-stats"]/text()')
# {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Is it possible to get the number of results using `rvest` or `rselenium` or an API?